# Создание нескольких таблиц SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Я создаю БД mydb в SQLite, в которой будет три таблицы tbl1, tbl2, tbl3.

Класс работы первой таблицы с БД:

```
public class DbHelperTbl1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelperTbl1 (@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, Constants.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Constants1.CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(Constants1.DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);      
        db.execSQL(Constants.DB_FOREIGN_KEY_ENABLE);
    }

}
```

Это SQL выражения:

```
public static final String _ID_TABLE = "_id";
public static final String FIELD_NAME = "name";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl1";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
    " (" + _ID_TABLE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    FIELD_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
public static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
```

Другие два полностью аналогичны, за исключением SQL выражений.

На сколько я понял, БД создается когда вызываю метод openDb класса DbManagerTbl1

```
public class DbManagerTbl1 implements DbManagerService {
    private Context context;
    private DbHelperTbl1 dbHelperTbl1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DbManagerTbl1(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelperTbl1 = new DbHelperTbl1(context);
    }

    public void openDb() {
        db = dbHelperTbl1.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void closeDb(){
        dbHelperTbl1.close();
    }
    ...

}
```

Таким образом создается БД с таблицей tbl1, далее наполняю ее данными, все работает.
Далее пытаюсь создать в этой БД следующую таблицу аналогичным образом. И получаю ошибку

```
SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tbl1
```

В чем тут проблема?
Да, этой таблицы действительно нет в базе, так я же и пытаюсь ее создать вызвав соответствующий метод openDb.
С первой же таблицей такая штука сработала, почему тут ошибка?

Comment: Если у вас одна БД, то она была создана при первом вызове `getWritableDatabase()` при последующих вызовах из любого хелпера, сколько бы их ни было, колбек `onCreate()` вызываться больше не будет. Вам нужно все таблицы создать в одном хелпере. И в принципе лучше использовать один хелпер и даже единственный его экземпляр на одну БД.

Comment: Спасибо! Для меня немного необычно, что нельзя менять структуру БД. Тогда вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Менять вы можете сколько угодно и когда угодно, но `onCreate()` для этого не подходит - он срабатывает на отсутсвие самой базы, а не таблицы в ней. Конструктор хелпера ведь не просит имя таблицы, откуда ему знать что вы хотите её создать...

Comment: @alex кто вам сказал что нельзя менять структуру БД? Можно! Вам же говорят, что onCreate срабатывает 1 раз. Добавляйте нужный код в onUpgrade, и меняйте (увеличивайте на 1) версию БД (последнее является ключевым)